# where the private key and public keys are getting stored in bigchainDB?

Tags: bigchaindb

assume that I am creating a key pair rahul,

I can get the publickey and private key by

````
const rahul = new BigchainDB.Ed25519Keypair()```



console.log('public key \n',rahul.publicKey);
console.log('private key \n',rahul.privateKey);```

apart from this, where can find the key pair of rahul in storage ?
````

Answer (score 0):

No, the public key is added to the transaction while the private key is used to sign transactions initiated by the user or entity. you are left with the responsibity of managing/storing them, (note : private keys shouldn't be handled by you because its meant to be private and handled by user himself)

You can read article and books on key management https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335325343_Key_management_for_blockchain_technology

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405959519301894